# SQL Error [1265] [01000]: Data truncated for column 'descval'

Tags: mysql, runtime-error

I'm getting this error but I do not have a column titled 'descval' so I'm not even sure where to begin looking for problem.  I'm sure this is a data problem but the error log in DBeaver offers very little to go on.

Below is the table that I am inserting the data into as well as the query that I'm using to do the insertion.  As you'll see, there is no descval column and yet that is what the error indicates.

```
Table that I'm inserting into:  
Call_Date (date)  
Call_Time (time)  
Call_Type (varchar(20))  
ANI (varchar(20))  
Acct_Key_Lookup (varchar(50))  
Call_Disposition (varchar(100))  
Result (varchar(100))  
Inbound_Group_Name (varchar(100))  
Inbound_Number (varchar(100))  
Talk_Time (bigint)  
Hold_Time (bigint)  
Wrap_Time (bigint)  
Client (varchar(20))  
Acct_Key_TCN (varchar(100))  
Description (varchar(100))  
DataSource (varchar(100))  
Debtor_Key_Lookup (varchar(50))  
agent_hunt_group (varchar(100))  
Agent_ID (varchar(50))

Query:
insert into `default`.tcn_meduit_calls (Call_Date, Call_Time, 
Call_Type, ANI, Acct_Key_Lookup, Call_Disposition, `Result`, 
Inbound_Group_Name, 
Inbound_Number, Talk_Time, Hold_Time, Wrap_Time, Client, 
Acct_Key_TCN, Description, DataSource, Debtor_Key_Lookup, 
agent_hunt_group, Agent_ID)
select
convert(concat(substr(tmcs.`date`,7,2),'-',substr(tmcs.`date`,1,2),'- 
',substr(tmcs.`date`,4,2)),date),
convert(concat(
case when right(tmcs.`time`,2) = 'AM' or left(tmcs.`time`,2) = '12' 
then 
    left(tmcs.`time`,locate(':',tmcs.`time`)-1)
else 
    left(tmcs.`time`,length(tmcs.`time`)- 
(locate(':',tmcs.`time`)-1))+12 end, ':',
substr(tmcs.`time`,locate(':',tmcs.`time`)+1,2),':','00'),Time),
substr(tmcs.`call type`,1,20),
coalesce(tmcs.`dialed number`,tmcs.`tcn dialed number`,tmcs.`phone 
number`),
case when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then 
(select tppl.Account_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl where tmcs.`phone number` = 
tppl.Phone_Number order by tppl.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then
(select tppl2.Account_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl2 where tmcs.`tcn dialed 
number` = tppl2.Phone_Number order by tppl2.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tppl3.Account_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl3 where tmcs.`dialed number` 
= tppl3.Phone_Number and tmcs.`debtor number` = tppl3.Debtor_Number 
limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then
(select tppl4.Account_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl4 where tmcs.`phone number` = 
tppl4.Phone_Number order by tppl4.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then
(select tppl5.Account_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl5 where tmcs.`tcn dialed 
number` = tppl5.Phone_Number order by tppl5.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tppl6.Account_Number
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl6 where tmcs.`dialed number` 
= tppl6.Phone_Number and tmcs.`debtor number` = tppl6.Account_Number 
limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then 
(select tapl.EncounterID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl where tapl.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`phone number` order by tapl.EncounterID limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then 
(select tapl2.EncounterID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl2 where tapl2.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`tcn dialed number` order by tapl2.EncounterID limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tapl3.EncounterID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl3 where tapl3.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`dialed number` order by tapl3.EncounterID limit 1)
else 'UNKNOWN' end,
tmcs.`call disposition`, tmcs.`result`, tmcs.`inbound group name`, 
trim(leading '+' from tmcs.`inbound number`), 
case when tmcs.`agent call talk duration` = '' then cast(0 as 
unsigned) else cast(tmcs.`agent call talk duration` as unsigned) end,
case when tmcs.`linkback duration` = '' then cast(0 as unsigned) else 
(cast(tmcs.`linkback duration` as unsigned)) - 
(case when tmcs.`agent call talk duration` = '' then 0 else 
cast(tmcs.`agent call talk duration` as unsigned) end) end,
case when tmcs.`agent call wrap up duration` = '' then cast(0 as 
unsigned) else cast(tmcs.`agent call wrap up duration` as unsigned) 
end,
case when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then 
(select tppl.Client_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl where tmcs.`phone number` = 
tppl.Phone_Number order by tppl.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then
(select tppl2.Client_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl2 where tmcs.`tcn dialed 
number` = tppl2.Phone_Number order by tppl2.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'CLT') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tppl3.Client_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl3 where tmcs.`dialed number` 
= tppl3.Phone_Number and tmcs.`debtor number` = tppl3.Debtor_Number 
limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then
(select tppl4.Client_ID 
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl4 where tmcs.`phone number` = 
tppl4.Phone_Number order by tppl4.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then
(select tppl5.Client_ID 
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl5 where tmcs.`tcn dialed 
number` = tppl5.Phone_Number order by tppl5.Account_Number limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'PCB') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tppl6.Client_ID 
from `default`.tcn_pcb_phone_lookup tppl6 where tmcs.`dialed number` 
= tppl6.Phone_Number and tmcs.`debtor number` = tppl6.Account_Number 
limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then 
(select tapl.ClientID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl where tapl.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`phone number` order by tapl.EncounterID limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'manual' then 
(select tapl2.ClientID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl2 where tapl2.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`tcn dialed number` order by tapl2.EncounterID limit 1)
when (`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'PCB' or 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) = 'SAR') and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tapl3.ClientID 
from `default`.tcn_ahc_phone_lookup tapl3 where tapl3.PhoneNumber = 
tmcs.`dialed number` order by tapl3.EncounterID limit 1)
else 'UNKNOWN' end,
substr(tmcs.`debtor number`,1,100),
substr(tmcs.description,1,100),
case when `default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'NA' then 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.`agent's hunt group`) else 
`default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) end,
case when `default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' and 
tmcs.`call type` = 'inbound' then 
(select tppl.Debtor_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl where tmcs.`phone number` = 
tppl.Phone_Number order by tppl.Account_Number limit 1)
when `default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' and tmcs.`call 
type` = 'manual' then
(select tppl2.Debtor_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl2 where tmcs.`tcn dialed 
number` = tppl2.Phone_Number order by tppl2.Account_Number limit 1)
when `default`.id_datasource(tmcs.description) = 'CLT' and tmcs.`call 
type` = 'outbound' then 
(select tppl3.Debtor_Number 
from `default`.tcn_pmab_phone_lookup tppl3 where tmcs.`dialed number` 
= tppl3.Phone_Number and tmcs.`debtor number` = tppl3.Debtor_Number 
limit 1)
else '' end,
tmcs.`agent's hunt group`,
substr(tmcs.`partner agent id`,1,50)
from `default`.tcn_meduit_calls_staging tmcs 
where tmcs.transform_status is null
```

My query above calls the a function I created and that is where the descval exists.  My function is named id.datasource (code below).  In the source table, the source field is varchar(200) and, initially, I did declare descval as varchar(100) but I've changed it since to varchar(200) and, yet, I still get the error.

```
DELIMITER $$

create function `default`.id_datasource (descval varchar(200))
returns varchar(10)
begin  
    declare datasource varchar(10) default '';
    SET datasource =   
        case 
            when descval like '%CLT%' then 'CLT'  
            when descval like '%PCB%' then 'PCB'  
            when descval like '%SAR%' then 'SAR'
            when descval like '%GAI%' then 'SAR'
            else 'NA' 
        end; 
    return datasource;
end
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Without your taböle definition and inserted row we can't tell you  nothing at all qabout your problem, the error tells you many things for example you try to enter soe value in descval that is to big for the datatype of decval

Comment: Identifying the row is the problem.  There are 110,000 records that I'm traversing in my query and inserting into my table.  descval is NOT a column in my table so I have no idea where that is coming from.  I'll add the table definition and attach the very long query but my thought was that they would not be useful in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Any triggers on your table by chance?

Comment: Do you have the column `descval` in some other table?

Comment: Stu - I didn't know triggers existed until this moment - very interesting functionality - but no, I do not have any triggers in place.

Comment: Do you see `descval` in `information_schema.columns`?

Comment: Barmar - I did create a SQL function (totally forgot) that does use a temp variable called descval - I'll add the code to the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

The source field (description) that I was using within the body of my query was defined as varchar(200) but I was calling a function that I created that declares the same variable as varchar(100).  I need to change the function to declare it as varchar(200), drop the function and then re-create it.